# A way to not write long defer using the latest err value?

Tags: go, defer-keyword

I have this code that works.

```golang
func (r *repoPG) WithTransaction(txFunc func() error) (err error) {
    tx := db.NewTx()

    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("panic: %v", r)
            tx.Rollback()
        } else if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        } else {
            tx.Commit()
        }
    }()

    err = txFunc()
    return
}
```

I want to avod every time to write that long `defer`, so I'm trying to write a func like this:

```golang
func TxDefer(tx, err) {
  if r := recover(); r != nil {
    err = fmt.Errorf("panic: %v", r)
    tx.Rollback()
  } else if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
  } else {
    tx.Commit()
  }
}
```

using it like:

```golang
func (r *repoPG) WithTransaction(txFunc func() error) (err error) {
    tx := db.NewTx()

    defer TxDefer(tx, err)

    err = txFunc()
    return
}
```

But this is miserably incorrect because the `err` it's always the original one, not the result of `txFunc()`, right?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why use defer at all, if it complicates things? Also I'm sure `tx.Commit` etc return their own `error`. Using defer, any of those cleanup errors are not being captured.

Comment: Under what circumstances that code is going to panic?

Comment: In several circumstances, the methods being long and full of insidious things. Defer is what it's for, right? Are there any contraindications to using `*err`?

Comment: Given how small is `WithTransaction`'s body I think it does not make much sense to extract deferred finalizer into a separate named function. If you keep it a closure you don't need to jump through the hoops to establish write access to `err`. Also you can simply call `return txFunc()`, it will assign named result too.

Comment: As mentioned above, `tx.Commit()` and `tx.Rollback()` can produce errors too, replacing `err` might be not the best strategy since it discards original error. Alternatively you may want to wrap original error with tx error `err = fmt.Errorf("failed to rollback tx, %s: %w", rollbackErr, err)`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the address of the error to the function. This allows the function to access the current value of the caller's variable. It also allows function to set the variable.

Rollback and Commit return errors. These errors should be returned to the caller.

```
func TxDefer(tx Transaction, perr *error) {
  if r := recover(); r != nil {
    *perr = fmt.Errorf("panic: %v", r)
    tx.Rollback()
  } else if *perr != nil {
    err = tx.Rollback()
    if err != nil {
       // replace original error with rollback error
       *perr = err
    }
  } else {
    *perr = tx.Commit()
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func (r *repoPG) WithTransaction(txFunc func() error) (err error) {
    tx := db.NewTx()
    defer TxDefer(tx, &err)
    err = txFunc()
    return
}
```

In the code above, the expression `*perr` evaluates to the current value of `err` in `WithTransaction`. The value of `err` in the question is the value of `err` at the time of the defer.

Comment: Is this line `} else if *err != nil {` the same of this: `} else if err != nil {`?